# Is there any form of developer's HUD built into Qt?

Tags: qt, qt5.6

I have a Qt application misbehaving on macOS. The UI is garbled in various ways. As part of diagnosing this I would like to hit a hot key and bring up a HUD to interactively browse Qt's internal resources it uses to render itself, such as OpenGL textures and other surfaces to see what it has cached.

Does it have such a feature?

Answer (score 0):

KDAB's [GammaRay](https://www.kdab.com/development-resources/qt-tools/gammaray/) is what you are looking for.